# Objective-C 2.0 and Categories

Tags: objective-c, categories

In objective-c if I have a class such as "Foo", and have a category for that class "Foo (bar)", but do not implement all the methods declared in the category, would I have to redeclare them in a subclass before I define them?  My book says yes (not sure if this is a mistake, or has been changed), I don't see why this is the case.

Basically how do categories apply to subclasses?

Answer (score 1):

Categories are orthogonal to class hierarchy. They apply to the class on where they are defined. At runtime, the category methods are added to the method table of the class. Subclasses can use them as if they were regular methods.

Be sure to (re-)read [this chapter of Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) about the subject.

If you want to override a category method in a subclass, you can to either by declaring it in the class interface, or by declaring a category for the subclass.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to redeclare the method, but you must be able to "see" the declaration if you are calling it internally. (i.e. `#import 'Foo+bar.h'` in your subclasses `.m`).

It is, however, not a good idea to declare a method but not implement it. Your application will crash if `-[Foo someDeclaredButNotImplementdMethod]` is called. At least provide an empty implementations (e.g. `- (void)someDeclaredButNotImplementdMethod {}`).